# How to also target element's children with JavaScript's hasClass()?

Tags: javascript

I have a button in a plugin that contains an svg:

```
<button class="next"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" etc etc></svg></button>
```

Currently, the button is used to fire an event onMouseDown:

```
self._onMouseDown = function(e)
    {
       if (hasClass(target, 'next')) {
         self.prevMonth();
      }
    }
```

with hasClass targeting the button.

However, I've noticed that I cannot click the SVG to perform the function, only the button behind it.

Does anyone know of a way to make hasClass target an elements child elements as well?

(ps: in this project I cannot use JQuery)

Comment: Why not forget the `if` statement, and just add the mouse listener directly to the `<button>`? Then events will naturally bubble up, even if the child `<svg>` is clicked

Comment: @qxz That's part of the plugin. Don't really want to mess with it incase I break something.

Comment: Wait, what is the plugin? The code that attaches `self._onMouseDown`, the code in `self._onMouseDown`, both? What exactly *can* you mess with? If nothing, how do we help you? :D

Comment: Agreed, more info/context on where this code is would be very helpful.

Comment: @Amadan sorry, all of it is the plugin (except for my SVG). I guess I was just hoping to alter the hasClass function somehow

Comment: I was wondering would `pointer-events:none` on svg element will help? Can you try that

Comment: Sure, `function hasClass() { return true; }` should do it. :P Jokes aside, @anu's suggestion should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using css property `pointer-events:none`on your svg element.

It will instruct mouse event to go "through" the element and target whatever is "underneath" that element instead(in your case the button).
[More info here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Note:Check for browser compatibility though. I think it doesnt work for < IE11. Damn you IE

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to check if an element, or any of its parents, has a class, you could search through the `parentNode`s:

```
function hasClassOrParent(node, cls) {
  while (node) {
    if (hasClass(node, cls)) return true;
    node = node.parentNode;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Replacing `hasClass` with that function should work.